# MySql Database Hacked, NOT injections

Tags: mysql, database, security

Three weeks ago, I found a list of my website's users and info on Paste Bin giving away all privacy. I ran updates and protected against SQL Injections. I also added a pre-request to save the SQL in text format in a LOG table whenever user input is required to be able to analyse any injection if my protection wasn't enough.

Then today the same post was on Paste Bin again with recent entries so I checked the LOG table to find only clean entries. Is there anything else than injections I should worry about? The web seems to give info about Injections only!

Could they have had access to the dbpassword in a php file on the server and could they have connected from and external server?

Should I change the dbpassword frequently?

Are there any solution non-script wise like hosting security plan or something like that which should be efficient enough?

I am receiving physical threats from hacked users and would really like to close this quickly...

Comment: There are any number of ways in which your database could be compromised.  You might want to explain your application architecture a bit as well as how you work with the database and passwords.  In the meantime change your database passwords including root, right now.

Comment: I will keep the followup here because obviously all of you had great advices and I put up a list to go through which I am halfway right now but for some of the operations I will have to call my Hosting provider tomorrow morning. Thanks again and I will update this question once I get a hang of everything!

Answer (score 7):

If you're implementing your own protection against user input, you're probably doing it wrong.  Most standard database libraries will give you a way of passing in parameters to queries where it will be sanitised properly, and these will have been coded with more things in mind than you're probably aware of.  Reinventing the wheel in anything security-related is a bad idea!

Other things to worry about:

- Password policy (strong passwords)
- Access to your database server (is it firewalled?)
- SSH access to your server (again, firewalled?)
- Keeping all of your software up-to-date

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the other answers that you've had so far.  If someone is posting the contents of your database online then you need to assume that the server(s) running the application and database have been compromised, as once they've gained initial access, it's likely that they'll have placed root-kits or similar tools onto the server to keep access to it.

As to how they got in there's a number of potential options, depending on the architecture of your solution, and it's imposssible to say which is the case without more details.  Some of the more likely options options would be

- SSH passwords
- Administrative web apps (e.g. PHPMyAdmin) with common passwords or vulnerabilities
- Access via hosting service (e.g. weak passwords on administrative login panels)
- If the site is PHP based Remote File Inclusion issues are a distinct possibility

If you can I'd recommend engaging a forensics or incident response company to help you recover the data and rebuild, but failing that I'd recommend getting a backup from before the compromise and using that to rebuild the server, then ensure that all software is updated and patched and passwords are not the same as the compromised system, before bringing it online.

Answer (score 2):

The best protection for this is to allow connections to the mysql database only from the machine where your application runs.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure, network access to the MySQL database is "need to know" - in most cases this is a simplye `bind-address 127.0.0.1`.

Next change the DB password, just because yes, you can (C)

Now think of this: If somebody got your DB passwd from your PHP files, you already are in deep s***t: Nothing stops him or her from just repeating that stunt! You need to audit your application for backdoors (after the fact problem) and how the guys got in there (before the fact problem). Check your apache logs for requests with unusual `GET` parameters - a filename in there mostly is a dead givaway.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Razvan.  Also if you're running any CMS or prepackaged web pages, make sure they're the latest version.  They most likely access as localhost from the web server.  Hackers follow the change logs of those and every time a security patch is released, they attack published vulnerabilities on servers running the older version.  It's often performed in bulk by crawlers.  Odds are they have a database with your server listed as running old versions of things.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to ensure that this "php file" containing the DB password(s) is not within the web root directory, otherwise they could simply access it like: http://mydomain.com/dbpassword.php.

Second, immediately change the passwords used to access your database.

Third, ensure that mysql will only accept connections from 'localhost', vs allowing connections from anywhere; '%'. And if it is a dedicated server, then you should "harden" the box and add an IP rule to IPTables where mysql access is only allowed from the server's IP. These changes would ensure that if they did get your db username/password creds, they can not access the database from a remote computer, instead they would have to exploit your application, or ssh into your server to gain access to your database.

Next, you should disable all user accounts to your site, and force them to update their passwords using a closed loop verification process. This will ensure no ongoing malicious activity is occurring with your users or their accounts.

These are just a few steps to take, there are others such as tracking local users login activity. It is possible that one of your system's user accounts has been compromised (rooted). The point is, you need to consider all points of access to your system and services therein, if you are unable to do it, it may be time to hire or contract a seasoned sysadmin to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is shared web hosting, and another user is logged in with shell access and is able to guess the path to your web root, and the password configuration (PHP or other script) file is world readable, then the user can read it.

This is one of the most common vulnerabilities and is very easy to exploit.

If this is the case:

To correct the issue, you need to move the configuration file out of your web root folder and/or change the permissions on it so that it's not world readable, and then change your database password.

Most likely, the user would not be able to inject anything into your application.

Changing the database server so that it's only accessible locally or to your web server would do no good, since the malicious user would be on the same web server and still be able to access it.

If you did not see any malicious queries, then they are probably accessing your db via the MySQL command line (or PHPMyAdmin or other tool), and not through your application.

Enabling the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) would allow you to see all queries in plain text in the log, but if this is shared web (and MySQL server) hosting, you probably won't be able to enable this.

This is something you may wish to report to your web host. They may be able to find the attacker and suspend their account or provide you with evidence.